# Input radio change theme and saving in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, local-storage

For the moment, I have this for switching my theme:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" class="switch">

<div id="Switch">
  <a href="#" rel="css/style.css">My theme 1</a>
  <a href="#" rel="css/style2.css">My theme 2</a>
</div>
```

```js
$("div#Switch a").click(function() {
  $("link.switch").attr("href", $(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

I want to find a solution to transform the links into a radio button and the choice is saved in localStorage and called back when refreshing.

Comment: What do you need help with? Do you want us to do the work for you or are you having issues with something particular?

Comment: I guess replacing `<a>` with `<input>` should be fairly easy, so - do you have any problems with `localStorage`? Only the setItem() and the getItem() methods are the once that concern you, and the docs have a few examples to get started - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a resource for how the HTML DOM should look like for radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
  <label for="huey">Huey</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
  <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
  <label for="louie">Louie</label>
</div>
```

---

Here's how you use jQuery for listening to radio button interactions if you don't specify a class or id for it, where you simply replace the `input[type=radio]` with your class/id:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

---

Here's how you use localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

var val = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

If you're saving objects in localStorage i recommend that you use `JSON` to serialize/deserialize it:

```
// Convert object to JSON string
var json = JSON.toJSON(object);

// Convert object from JSON to string
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

and save that in the converted JSON string to localStorage and parse it when fetching it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make a radio button:

```
<input type='radio' id='ww' name='xyz'/>
<input type='radio' name='xyz'/>
```

When change to radio button occurs:

```
if (document.getElementById('ww').checked) {
  console.log(document.getElementById('ww').value);
}
```

For localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('k','xyz');

var a = localStorage.getItem('k');
```